# OMNET++ installation error in Windows 10

Tags: gcc, installation, omnet++

I am trying to install omnet 5.1.1 in my windows 10 64 bit. everything was ok untill this error message showed.

```
/e/Mansoor/E/Simulator/omnet/omnetpp-5.1.1$ ./configure

configure: loading site script /mingw64/etc/config.site
checking build system type... x86_64-w64-mingw32
checking host system type... x86_64-w64-mingw32
configure: -----------------------------------------------
configure: reading configure.user for your custom settings
configure: -----------------------------------------------
checking for clang... no
checking for icc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/e/Mansoor/E/Simulator/omnet/omnetpp-5.1.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Kindly suggest me how may i debug this?

Comment: So what does `config.log` say?

Comment: Missing writing privileges maybe? A security tool / virus scanner that blocks the work of the configure script??